# When Eldritch Poisoner's Arcanotoxin upgrades, does it do 2 types of ability damage at once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, poison

When an Arcanotoxin is improved at 3rd level, and you choose to add another type of ability damage, does it stack with the already selected Str or Dex damage, or can you choose to create that type of poison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dealing damage to multiple ability scores simultaneously *probably* requires a discovery

The [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) archetype [eldritch poisoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/eldritch-poisoner-alchemist-archetype)'s supernatural ability arcanotoxin says, in part, that…

> At 1st level, an eldritch poisoner must choose whether her arcanotoxin deals Strength or Dexterity damage. At 3rd level and every 2 alchemist levels thereafter, she can enhance her arcanotoxin in one of the following ways. She can't select the same improvement twice in a row.

…And one of those improvements is…

> - Select one additional form of ability damage: Charisma, Dexterity, Intelligence, Strength, or Wisdom.

…But an [eldritch poisoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/eldritch-poisoner-alchemist-archetype) unique discovery is the extraordinary ability combine toxins:

> An eldritch poisoner can diversify her arcanotoxin, dealing damage to any two ability scores with a single dose. The alchemist must already know how to target both ability scores with her arcanotoxin. A combined toxin reduces the damage die of its arcanotoxin by one step, to a minimum of 1 point of ability damage to each ability score.

…And this discovery strongly implies that it takes the discovery combine toxin to deal ability damage to more than one ability score at a time rather than this being a feature of the appropriately improved the arcanotoxin. (While the supernatural ability arcanotoxin *is* sort of vague, I couldn't find any questions addressing this concern on Paizo's messageboards; it's your call whether this absence makes a case for or against either position weaker or stronger.)

In other words, for example, I think an eldritch poisoner who picks the above improvement for his initially Dexterity-damage-only arcanotoxin deals with his arcanotoxin  *either* 1d2 points of Dexterity damage *or* 1d2 points of Wisdom damage. The same eldritch poisoner that also picked the discovery combined toxin could deal *either* 1d2 points of Dexterity damage *or* 1d2 points of Wisdom damage *or* 1 point of Dexterity damage and 1 point of Wisdom damage.

Answer (score -1):

If you take the **additional ability** advancement, then yes. It will deal damage to both abilities at once.

> At 1st level, an eldritch poisoner must choose whether her arcanotoxin
>   deals Strength or Dexterity damage. At 3rd level and every 2 alchemist
>   levels thereafter, she can enhance her arcanotoxin in one of the
>   following ways. She can't select the same improvement twice in a row.
>
> - Select one additional form of ability damage: Charisma, Dexterity,
>     Intelligence, Strength, or Wisdom.
>     Blockquote
> - Grant an onset time of 1 round, or increase an existing onset time by 2 rounds (maximum 11 rounds).
> - **Increase the ability damage die by one step (maximum 1d6).**
> - Increase the number of consecutive saves required to cure the poison by 1 (maximum 3).
> - Increase the frequency by 2 rounds (maximum 10 rounds).